How to correct the orientation of a raster stack
I have a NetCDF file of daily data. I converted it to a raster stack, but its orientation is not correct (I have attached the image with this). How do I correct this? I am also attching my code with this text. Image of raster_stack
Also, tell if anyone idea, how do I extract annual data from these raster files into Excel format. I have raster files from 1955 to 2023 with daily rainfall data, I want to exctract annual rainfall data according to the administrative shapefile I have.
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

ncfile <- nc_open("RF25_ind1955_rfp25.nc")

variable_name <- "RAINFALL"
rainfall_data <- ncvar_get(ncfile, variable_name)
lon <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "LONGITUDE")
lat <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "LATITUDE")
time <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "TIME")
lon_range <- range(lon)
lat_range <- range(lat)

raster_stack <- stack()
for (i in 1:dim(rainfall_data)[3]) {
  raster_layer <- raster(matrix(rainfall_data[,,i], nrow = nrow(rainfall_data), ncol = ncol(rainfall_data)),
                         xmn = lon_range[1], xmx = lon_range[2], ymn = lat_range[1], ymx = lat_range[2],
                         crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
  raster_stack <- addLayer(raster_stack, raster_layer)
}

plot(raster_stack)

flip <- t(flip(raster_stack))
plot(flip)


Hi NEERAJ YADAV, welcome to SO. Please do not add code as an image for these reasons. Instead, add the code in a codeblock e.g three backticks "````" (without the quotes), then add code on a new line, then three backticks on a new line after the code

And you need to provide a minimal, reproducible example when asking a question. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Also, please ask only one question per post. If you have multiple questions, ask them as separate questions.

Also, the reason the orientation of your data is not correct is because you used flip(). If you just run plot(rasster_stack), is that want you were wanting?

first I plot using the code plot(raster_stack), the orientation was not correct, the map was horizontal as i provided the image, it is the plot of this code only plot(raster_stack). But when i tried another way flip(), it also didnt correct its orientation.

Not sure if this is the data you used - it would have been nice if you referenced this in your question - but I found some yearly gridded rainfall (0.25 x 0.25) data in NetCDF format looking not that bad here.
If you really want to decompose the file with {ncdf4} and built your raster object from scratch, you need to transpose your matrix and flip() your raster in the end:
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

ncfile <- nc_open("RF25_ind1955_rfp25.nc")

# using only the first iteration as demo
i = 1

r1 <- raster(matrix(rainfall_data[,,i], nrow = nrow(rainfall_data), ncol = ncol(rainfall_data)) |> t(),
             xmn = lon_range[1], 
             xmx = lon_range[2], 
             ymn = lat_range[1], 
             ymx = lat_range[2],
             crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") |> flip()

plot(r1)

Alternatively, you could also just make use of raster::brick() - which seems to handle this natively - or, since {raster} has actually been replaced by {terra}, terra::rast():
library(raster)

r2 <- brick("RF25_ind1955_rfp25.nc")
r2
#> class      : RasterBrick 
#> dimensions : 129, 135, 17415, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent     : 66.375, 100.125, 6.375, 38.625  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source     : RF25_ind1955_rfp25.nc 
#> names      : X19724, X19725, X19726, X19727, X19728, X19729, X19730, X19731, X19732, X19733, X19734, X19735, X19736, X19737, X19738, ... 
#> TIME (days since 1900-12-31): 19724, 20088 (min, max)
#> varname    : RAINFALL

library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71

r3 <- rast("RF25_ind1955_rfp25.nc")
r3
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 129, 135, 365  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent      : 66.375, 100.125, 6.375, 38.625  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#> source      : RF25_ind1955_rfp25.nc 
#> varname     : RAINFALL (Rainfall) 
#> names       : RAINF~19724, RAINF~19725, RAINF~19726, RAINF~19727, RAINF~19728, RAINF~19729, ... 
#> unit        :          mm,          mm,          mm,          mm,          mm,          mm, ...

But you might want to clean up the time attribute in this case via raster::setZ() and terra::time() respectively.
Edit:
Aggregating your daily raster data to yearly sums and extracting values based on some vector geometry is pretty straightforward with {terra}:
# fixing time attribute
time(r3) <- seq(as.Date("1955-01-01"), as.Date("1955-12-31"), by = "day")

# get some random administrative data as polygons
adm <- geodata::gadm("India", level = 2, path = tempfile())

# apply a function on your SpatRaster object based on time
ysum <- tapp(r3, "years", fun = sum)
# alternatively just use `sum(r3)`

# extract values from SpatRaster by SpatVector object
extract(ysum, adm[42, ])
#>   ID   y_1955
#> 1  1 3371.446
#> 2  1 3307.212
#> 3  1 2489.370
#> 4  1 3252.928
#> 5  1 2926.972
#> 6  1 2692.525

Created on 2024-05-10 with reprex v2.1.0

I appreciate your assistance, @dimfalk. The solution you provided is effective for my IMD data analysis. I used 'terra' to process and extract yearly values for the districts outlined in my shapefile. However, when I execute the code, it returns 4686 rows instead of the expected 595, which matches the number of districts in my shapefile. Some information about my shapefile: Simple feature collection with 595 features and 10 fields; Gmtry: MULTIPOLYGON; Dim: XY, XYZ; Bounding box:  xmin: 68.12382 ymin: 6.762208 xmax: 97.40784 ymax: 37.08933
z_range:       zmin: 0 zmax: 0
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

In addition to extracting rainfall data, I also need to obtain temperature data from IMD for the same districts and with the same resolution. Could you please provide guidance on how I can accomplish this? Any assistance on extracting temperature data in alignment with the resolution of the rainfall data would be highly appreciated.

Happy to help. That's probably because the values returned by extract() are per pixel, whereas you'd need some further aggregation per admin level, i.e. you'd need to compute means per feature of your annual precipitation sums. Check the fun=mean argument. But that's just a guess since I don't have your data. Regarding your temperature data - just follow the same procedure. Acquire a dataset, calculate a mean value on a raster basis (if you're dealing with daily values), and extract mean values per feature.
